# Centering textbutton to screen libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I am currently creating a game using LibGDX and I am creating my Title Screen at the moment. I am having trouble centering TextButtons on the screen, I can get them centered fine if the set the width of the TextButton to the width of the stage but then anywhere you click left to right of that button allows the button to be pressed and not if you're just clicking on the button itself.

How could I get the TextButtons centered to the game screen and centered on each other? I've got three TextButtons(New Game, Continue and Exit Game).

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Edit:

Here is the code for my three buttons.

```
btnNG = new TextButton("New Game", btnStyle[0]) {
    {
        setName("New Game");
        addListener(new InputListener() {
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent e, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                g.debugOut(btnNG.getName(), "touchDown?");
                return true;
            }

            public void touchUp(InputEvent e, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                g.debugOut(btnNG.getName(), "touchUp?");
                //g.switchScreen(new Mainscreen(g));
            }
        });
        setWidth(sTitle.getWidth());
        setPosition(0, (getHeight() * 2.5f));
    }
};

btnContinue = new TextButton("Continue", btnStyle[0]) {
    {
        setName("Continue");
        addListener(new InputListener() {
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent e, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                g.debugOut(btnContinue.getName(), "touchDown?");
                return true;
            }

            public void touchUp(InputEvent e, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                g.debugOut(btnContinue.getName(), "touchUp?");
            }
        });
        setWidth(sTitle.getWidth());
        setPosition(0, (getHeight() * 1.4f));
    }
};

btnExit = new TextButton("Exit Game", btnStyle[0]) {
    {
        setName("Exit Game");
        addListener(new InputListener() {
            public boolean touchDown(InputEvent e, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                g.debugOut(btnExit.getName(), "touchDown?");
                return true;
            }

            public void touchUp(InputEvent e, float x, float y, int pointer, int button) {
                g.debugOut(btnExit.getName(), "touchUp?");
                //Gdx.app.exit();
            }
        });
        setWidth(sTitle.getWidth());
        setPosition(0, (getHeight() * .3f));
    }
};
```

That is what I have so far, it is centered but doing so allows it to be clicked by pressing anywhere on the screen to the left/right of the actual text.

Comment: Please include some of your code that is creating the button and attaching the texture to it.

Comment: I updated my post with some code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess sTitle is your stage object...

---

Are you adding buttons directly to the stage?

If so, I'd recommend using a Table.

```
Table menuTable = new Table();
menuTable.add(btnNG);
menuTable.row();
menuTable.add(btnContinue);
menuTable.row();
menuTable.add(btnExit);
menuTable.setFillParent(true);
sTitle.addActor(menuTable);
```

**Note 1:**
Remove all setSize and setPosition calls on all buttons.
Remove other addActor calls.

**Note 2:**
For advanced features, refer [TableLayout](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout)

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. I didn't know about this feature in LibGDX.

Answer (score 2):

You could put them into the `Table` container, and allow it to take care about aligning:

```
Table container = new Table();
container.add(btnNG).expandX().center().row();
container.add(btnContinue).expandX().center().row();
container.add(btnExit).expandX().center().row();
// add container to some Stage
```

Also, you could call `padTop(x)` after each `center()` to define offsets.
Please read more [here](https://github.com/EsotericSoftware/tablelayout) about table layout.

Comment: Center should be the deffault in the tablelayout right?

Answer (score 1):

Set the x of each button to be the same so that they will be aligned. Set the x position to the half of  the width of the  screen minus the half the width of your button like this --> ( widthOfScreen / 2 ) - ( buttonWidth / 2 )